# no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a friday night funkin' AI.I tried to use threads becuase it would take too long without, but they are not working

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <thread>

    using namespace std;

    void left(int a) {
        HDC _hdc = GetDC(NULL);
        COLORREF l = GetPixel(_hdc, 1105, 177);
        if ((int)GetRValue(l) == 194 && (int)GetGValue(l) == 75 && (int)GetGValue(l) == 153 || (int)GetRValue(l) == 170 && (int)GetGValue(l) == 110 && (int)GetGValue(l) == 161) {
            keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);


        }
        else {

            keybd_event(VK_LEFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            std::cout << a;
        }
    }
    void right(int b) {
        //right
        HDC _hdc = GetDC(NULL);
        COLORREF r = GetPixel(_hdc, 1583, 164);

        if ((int)GetRValue(r) == 249 && (int)GetGValue(r) == 57 && (int)GetGValue(r) == 63 || (int)GetRValue(r) == 203 || (int)GetGValue(r) == 99 || (int)GetGValue(r) == 107) {
            keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);


        }
        else {
            keybd_event(VK_RIGHT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        }
        cout << b;
    }

    int main()
    {


        


        while (!GetAsyncKeyState(0x57)) {

            
            std::thread ri(right, 10);
            std::thread le(left, 10 );
            




        }


    }
```

the errors are:
no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list

```
'std::thread::thread': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
```

.............................................................

Comment: Works for me - turned into a [mcve] - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Y7aPenqvT  Now add the code back until it breaks.

Comment: Don't use `using namespce std;`, by `include <iostream>` you included `<ios>` which defines `std::left`, `std::right`. Compiler doesn't know which `left` you want to pass to thread constructor arguments, your or the one defined in `<ios>`. You can write `std::thread ri(::right, 10);` to select the global version. Do the same with `left`.